# Is it possible to pass a DbContext from one project into another project?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

**The scenario:**
I have a couple websites that I'm rebuilding with Blazor, all do e-commerce. What I want to do is extract the accounting logic (i.e. `Orders`, `OrderItems`, `Accounts`, `Transactions`, etc) and data operations into an
"Accounting" DLL so I don't have to repeat the code.

I've got the above `Entities` defined in the DLL, then in the `WebApp.Server`'s `DbContext` I have the appropriate `DbSets`.

In the "Accounting" DLL, I have an interface:

```
public interface IDbAccountringService
{
    DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

    //etc
}
```

which the DbContext in `WebApp.Server` implements:

```
public class Db : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<User>, IDbAccountringService
{
    public Db(
        DbContextOptions options,
        IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the "Accounting" DLL, I have the following generic class:

```
public class DbAccountingService<T> where T : DbContext, IDbAccountringService
{
    DbContext dbContext { get; set; }

    public DbAccountingService(DbContext T)
    {
        dbContext = T;
    }

    public Account[] GetAccounts()
    {
        //The compiler doesn't see Accounts
        return dbContext.Accounts.ToArray();

        //It also doesn't see Accounts on itself
        return this.Accounts.ToArray();

        // However, it does see all the DbContext methods
        dbContext.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```

which I instantiate and use in my controller:

```
[Route("accounting/accounts")]
[ApiController]
public class JournalController : BaseApiController
{
    DbAccountingService<Db> _dbAccountingService;

    public JournalController(Db db, MtGlobals mtGlobals) : base(mtGlobals)
    {
        _dbAccountingService = new DbAccountingService<Db>(db);
    }

    [HttpGet("get-accounts")]
    public Account[] GetAccounts()
    {
        return _dbAccountingService.GetAccounts();
    }
}
```

As the comments in `DbAccountingService<T>` indicate, the compiler recognizes that `dbContext` is in fact a `DbContext`, but it doesn't recognize that it also implements `IDbAccountringService`.

I'm a little fuzzy on generics, though I usually get them working, however, here, no luck.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? I want to extract all the data operations into the "Accounting" DLL so that I don't have to write duplicate code for each website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `dbContext` field is of type `DbContext`:

```
DbContext dbContext { get; set; }

public DbAccountingService(DbContext T)
{
    dbContext = T;
}
```

Be aware, that you constructor parameter is of type `DbContext` too with parameter name `T`. So this T has nothing to do with the generic type parameter, it's just a parameter name.

You want the `dbContext` property to be the generic type:

```
T dbContext { get; set; }

public DbAccountingService(T context)
{
    dbContext = context;
}
```

The relevant par is, that your field has type T (because your where constraints this to implement interface `IAccountingService`.

Comment: Ok, that got me closer. Now the compiler doesn't recognize `ToArray()` in `return dbContext.Accounts.ToArray();`. Gonna update my question to reflect this. Thanks!

Comment: I guess `ToArray` is not really what you want here. If you simply want all records `ToList` or better `ToListAsync` is what you're looking for. If this doesn't solve your problem, pls check what type `Accounts` has.

Comment: Ach, I'm an idiot. Needed a using statement for `System.Linq`. Sometimes when I'm trying to make something work my code turns into a mess as I try different things. Not sure how that using went missing though. Your answer works. :)